# Beautiful soup (python) getting value of attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some messy soup that I've been trying to parse and I can't figure out how I would do it. On the page there are a bunch of `<div>` tags, and I can successfully traverse through them all to find the div that I want.

This div, has a custom attribute called `"data-series"`, the value of which seems to be some list of dictionaries containing lists. The value of the data-series attribute looks like this:

```
<div data-series=
'[{"label":"Series 1","data":[[0,0.01214697],[1,0.01139803],[2,0.0101848]],"color":"#27a9e3"},
{"label":"series 2","data":[[0,0.00745604375],[1,0.00885196875],[2,0.009824050833]],"color":"#ffb848"}]'....
```

It then continues on with some other custom attributes. I'm looking to pull out one of the numbers within this nested mess

The value I want to end up printing out is `0.01139803`. Within the list, it is found in the first dictionary, and is the value of the `"data"` key. But the value of the `"data"` key is in itself a list, and is the second element of the second nested element (`[1][1]`)

How would I pull this number out using beautiful soup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string for `data-series` is "JSON" (JavaScript Object Notation) data. You can use [`json.loads()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.loads) to process this string into Python data structures, then manipulate the result as you would any `list` and `dict`:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = '[{"label":"Series 1","data":[[0,0.01214697],[1,0.01139803],[2,0.0101848]],"color":"#27a9e3"},{"label":"series 2","data":[[0,0.00745604375],[1,0.00885196875],[2,0.009824050833]],"color":"#ffb848"}]'
>>> d = json.loads(s)
>>> d[0]['data'][1][1]
0.01139803
```